# Show login screen if user is not logged in when opening the app with react-navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-navigation

I am trying to create an app which has a main tab navigator, but if the user is not logged in, he/she should first see a login screen (however, I still want the user to get the option to skip login).

Also, if it's the first time the user opens the app, I want to show an onboarding/welcome screen where I explain the app.

Right now I am persisting my redux state with `redux-persist`, so when I open the app (i.e. without having it opened in the background), I want the user to see the `Login` screen if he/she is not logged in and the `Main` screen if the user is already logged in.

I have understood that I should have my main tab navigator nested in a stack navigator, such that the stack navigator has screens `WelcomeScreen`, `LoginScreen` and `Main`.

But how do I check if the user is logged in when the app is first opened and then redirect to the `Login` screen? I have looked at https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/blob/master/examples/ReduxExample/src/reducers/index.js, but it's not very intuitive what is meant by `firstAction`, `tempNavState`, and `secondAction`.

Do I need to create a middleware which checks if the user is logged in?

Answer (score 1):

In the root container check for login state if the user is loggedin or not and navigate accordingly.
See this post
[Login example](https://medium.com/the-react-native-log/building-an-authentication-flow-with-react-navigation-fb5de2203b5c) don't use async storage as he used in the post instead use redux state to determine user is logged in.
Another trick which is user friendly is to use [react-native-splash-screen](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen) and don't hide the splash screen using this package, wait for 2 seconds, so that redux-persist action is dispatched which restores the state and you can navigate during this time period. 
There will be no flickering using this method.

```
class AppWithNavigationState extends Component { 
    componentDidMount () { 
       setTimeout(()=>{ 
             if(this.props.loggedIn)
               { NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Main' }), } 

               setTimeout(SplashScreen.hide, 500)
     })
   }}
```

Comment: So I shouldn't add any login to the navigation reducer but simply do everything in my root container?

Comment: If you are using reducer and familiar with that than just dispatch a login action here in root reducer which will consider user is authenticated and a Navigation action will be triggered to navigate user to main screen.

Comment: I am not really sure how to do this. Should I create an action `checkIfUserIsLoggedIn` which will be called in `componentDidMount()` in my root component? And should the `checkIfUserIsLoggedIn` action contain dispatch `{ type: 'NOT_LOGGED_IN' }` so that I in my `navReducer` can reset navigation and navigate the user to login screen?

Comment: and where is my root component if I'm using the redux example proposed by `react-navigation`? Would it be `const AppWithNavigationState = ({ dispatch, nav }) => (
  <AppNavigator navigation={addNavigationHelpers({ dispatch, state: nav })} />
)`

Comment: See the updated answer make login default scene and use the above code